# How do I open this file through Web Browser (by launching an application through it)?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I have been trying to open a file with an extension .con ; which can only be opened by a specific application designed for the particular encoding of the video file it encapsulates.

However, the application can only be launched by a web browser.

The actual site that gives these files has the url of format
  `starplayer://<url>bolwl6pIrBrL1GEf7V%2F5Uy6eoFPW77xb5jrS%2BCqRb3%2BoaVq%2Fm3REcqkDQzNsEu2JH6Q2ysUzG73Is93y%2FhmRNK10znrzHKOmEcFITgVDIQeGRVDk7iMBeDth%2BNzmZLIK1yDadYIyBvUPAJ4JRiHzevUVOQ8FMVUJzWAtA5qONGf40KaP31iKvMICFJ3lRjI1cuclOg4KxDo8GeQfmsS7xCAbX1XSWMNlEQ%2Fqzaaht2Gj1fWfbgo%2FsJbGVGSr5swv7ezk4S77LV%2BLpT%2FGbRLbovv0X%2BE4bAQFBtbxfsJ%2BjRU%3D<base_url>http%3A%2F%2Fwww.etoosindia.com%2F<width>720<height>500<topmost>true<resizing>undefined<cookie>X2dhPUdBMS4yLjM2NzU5MzMwNS4xNDk4MjExMjczOyBjb29raWVfdWlkPTsgbWVtX25tPVpHOXVkQ0JqWVd4czsgbWVtX2lkPVoyeHdaM1ZvWkdOQWMyaGhjbXRzWVhObGNuTXVZMjl0OyBtZW1fY2Q9TnpreU1EVTU7IF9femxjbWlkPWhBZ1hnVGM4bU1Iekxl<caption>RXRvb3MlMjBJbmRpYQ%3D%3D`

The url opens up an IE frame in which the player loads.

Now I tried to open the file with typing this into the address bar;

```
starplayer://<url>C:\Users\Sciencyboi\Desktop\1.con
```

but it prompts to download the file instead of playing it.

I also tried this again with; (basically changing url and base url in the original one)

```
starplayer://<url>file:\\C:\Users\Sciencyboi\Desktop\1.mp4<base_url>undefined<width>720<height>500<topmost>true<resizing>undefined<cookie>X2dhPUdBMS4yLjM2NzU5MzMwNS4xNDk4MjExMjczOyBjb29raWVfdWlkPTsgbWVtX25tPVpHOXVkQ0JqWVd4czsgbWVtX2lkPVoyeHdaM1ZvWkdOQWMyaGhjbXRzWVhObGNuTXVZMjl0OyBtZW1fY2Q9TnpreU1EVTU7IF9femxjbWlkPWhBZ1hnVGM4bU1Iekxl<caption>RXRvb3MlMjBJbmRpYQ%3D%3D
```

and

```
starplayer://<url>1.con<base_url>C:\Users\Sciencyboi\Desktop\<width>720<height>500<topmost>true<resizing>undefined<cookie>X2dhPUdBMS4yLjM2NzU5MzMwNS4xNDk4MjExMjczOyBjb29raWVfdWlkPTsgbWVtX25tPVpHOXVkQ0JqWVd4czsgbWVtX2lkPVoyeHdaM1ZvWkdOQWMyaGhjbXRzWVhObGNuTXVZMjl0OyBtZW1fY2Q9TnpreU1EVTU7IF9femxjbWlkPWhBZ1hnVGM4bU1Iekxl<caption>RXRvb3MlMjBJbmRpYQ%3D%3D
```

it shows "navigation to the webpage cancelled"

I have also tried saving the source as an html file just after opening the IE frame before the player loaded, which is;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>FREE IIT JEE Main Coaching Online, IIT JEE Video Lectures & Free Mock Test</title>
  
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/starplayer/starplayer_config.js?v=20160801"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/starplayer/starplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var player;
 var recodePlayedTime = null;
 var userPlayedTime = 0;

 
 var step_;
 step_ = 10;
 
 function getStep() {
  return step_;
 }
   
 function setStep(step) {
  step_ = step;
 }

 function onMouseDbclick(x, y) {
  player.setFullscreen(!player.getFullscreen());
 }

 function onKeyDown(keycode) {
  if (window.event) {
   var type = window.event.srcElement.type;
   if (type == "text" || type == "textarea")
    return true;
  }
  switch (keycode) {
   case 13: // ENTER
    player.setFullscreen(true);
    break;
   case 32: // SPACE
    if (player.getPlayState() == PlayState.PLAYING)
     player.pause();
    else 
     player.play();
    break;
   case 38: // UP
    player.setVolume(player.getVolume() + 0.1);
    break;
   case 40: // DOWN
    player.setVolume(player.getVolume() - 0.1);
    break;
   case 37: // LEFT
    player.backward(getStep());
    break;
   case 39: // RIGHT
    player.forward(getStep());
    break;
   case 190: // >
    player.setRate(player.getRate() + 0.2);
    break;
   case 188: // <
    player.setRate((player.getRate() - 0.2) < 0.6 ? 0.6 : (player.getRate() - 0.2));
    break;
   case 77: // M
    player.setMute(!player.getMute());
    break;
   case 82: // R
    player.setRepeat(!player.getRepeat());
   default:
    return;
  }
  return false;
 }

 function onPlayStateChange(state) {
  switch (state) {
   case PlayState.PLAYING:    
    // 진도율 정보 전송
    if(checkTimeInterval == null) {
     checkViewTime();     
    }
    
    player.setVisible(true);
    break;
   case PlayState.PAUSED:
    // 시간체크 중지 
    if(userPlayedTime > 0) {
     clearInterval(recodePlayedTime);
     recodePlayedTime = null;
    } 
    break;
   case PlayState.STOPPED:
    // 시간체크 중지 
    if(userPlayedTime > 0) {
     clearInterval(recodePlayedTime);
     recodePlayedTime = null;
    }     
    player.setVisible(false);
    break;
   case PlayState.BUFFERING_STARTED:
    break;
  }
 }
   
 function onError(error_code) {
   player.setVisible(true);
   switch (error_code) {
    case StarPlayerError.MULTIPLE_CONNECTIONS:
     alert("Multi Connection Error");
   };
 }

 function onLoad(){
  var errMsg = '';
  
  if( errMsg != '' ) {
   alert(errMsg);
   self.close();
  } else {
   var config = {
     userId: 'ponipux@seekjobs4u.com',
     id: "starplayer",
     videoContainer: "video-container",
     controllerContainer: "controller-container",
     controllerUrl: "axissoft3.bin",
     visible:false
     
    };
    
   var startTime = '1';
    
   var media = {
     url: 'C:\Users\Sciencyboi\Desktop\1.mp4', 
     startTime: parseInt(startTime, 10),
     blockMessenger: false
   };
     
   player = new StarPlayer(config, media);
   player.onKeyDown = onKeyDown;
   player.onMouseDbclick = onMouseDbclick;
   player.onPlayStateChange = onPlayStateChange;
   player.onError = onError;    
  }
 }
 
 // 강의수강부분 체크 interval
    var checkTimeInterval = null;
 
    function checkViewTime() {
     var intervalTime = 1000 * 180;
     intervalTime = parseInt( intervalTime / player.getRate() );
     clearInterval(checkTimeInterval);
     checkTimeInterval = setInterval(function() { checkViewTimeAjax() }, intervalTime);
    }

    // 진도율 정보 전송
    function checkViewTimeAjax() {
     
     try{
      
      var duration = player.getDuration();
      var currentPostion = Math.round( player.getCurrentPosition() );
      var speed = player.getRate();
      
      var VP_TIME = userPlayedTime;
      var VP_RATE = Math.round( parseInt( currentPostion, 10 ) / parseInt( duration, 10 ) * 100 );
   
      if( isNaN(VP_RATE) || VP_RATE < 0 )
       VP_RATE = 0;
      
      var ppdSeq = '5721540';
      var godSeq = '12952';
      var vidSeq = '15698';
      var memCd = '796707';
      
      var param = {
           "PPD_SEQ" : ppdSeq
          , "GOD_SEQ" : godSeq
          , "VID_SEQ" : vidSeq          
          , "MEM_CD"  : memCd          
       , "VP_RATE" : VP_RATE        
       , "VP_TIME" : currentPostion
       , "VP_TIME_USER" : 0
       , "DURATION" : duration
      };
      
      $.ajax({
        url : '/common/checkViewTime.do' 
       , dataType : 'json'
       , method : 'post'
       , data : param
       , header : { Connection : close }
       , success : function(data) {
       
       }
      });
     }catch(e){
      alert(e); 
     }
    } 
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
 table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
 }
  
 table, td {
  border:0px solid red;
  padding:0;margin:0;
 }
</style>
 
</head>

<body style="margin: 0 0 0 0" onload="onLoad()" onkeydown="onKeyDown(event.keyCode)">
 <table id="player-container" style="width:720px;">
  <tr><td id="video-container" style="height:406px;background:#fafafa url('') no-repeat center center;"></td></tr>
  <tr><td id="controller-container" style="height:81px;"></td></tr>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The "var media = '---'" was changed by me in the above code to try and run the file.(with the other scripts in the "C:\js" directory)

The scripts mentioned in the above snippet are [here](https://anonfile.com/D1Jey2c7b1/js.zip)

I tried to run it in chrome, which didn't work, though running the file in Internet Explorer gives me the UI of the player which then just sits there like a duck.

I greatly appreciate any leads, suggestions or ways to do this particular thing.

Thank you!

Comment: General rule... get it working in Chrome before you worry about IE.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The application only works in an IE frame (blame the devs). The application even when launched by chrome, opens an IE frame in which the player loads.